# Magento2 GraphQL for Newly Added Product

Tags: magento2, graphql

I need to create GraphQL for newly added products.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I have gotten the latest product based on the created_at field and get latest 10 products in GraphQl

> app/code/Custom/NewlyProductGraphQl/etc/schema.graphqls

```
type Query {
        newlyCreatedProducts: [NewlyCreatedProducts] @resolver(class: "Custom\\NewlyProductGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\NewlyCreatedProducts")
    }
    type NewlyCreatedProducts {
        entity_id: Int
        name: String
        sku: String
    }
```

> app/code/Custom/NewlyProductGraphQl/Model/Resolver/NewlyCreatedProducts.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\NewlyProductGraphQl\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\Value;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ValueFactory;

/**
 * Class NewlyCreatedProducts
 */
class NewlyCreatedProducts implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var Visibility
     */
    protected $catalogProductVisibility;
    /**
     * @var ValueFactory
     */
    protected $valueFactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param ValueFactory $valueFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility        $catalogProductVisibility,
        ValueFactory      $valueFactory
    )
    {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->valueFactory = $valueFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param Field $field
     * @param $context
     * @param ResolveInfo $info
     * @param array|null $value
     * @param array|null $args
     * @return Value|mixed
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field       $field,
                    $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array       $value = null,
        array       $args = null
    ) {
        $data = $this->getNewlyProductCollection();
        $result = function () use ($data) {
            return !empty($data) ? $data : [];
        };
        return $this->valueFactory->create($result);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNewlyProductCollection(): array
    {
        $productData = [];
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection = $collection->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize(10)
            ->setCurPage(1);
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            array_push($productData, $product->getData());
        }
        return $productData ?: [];
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
query{
  newlyCreatedProducts{
    entity_id
    name
    sku
  }
}
```

[image]

**Thanks.**